# Size of login form is too large

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Ive got my login form too wide, it takes 80% of the pages width as you could see the picture below.
I'm using default bootstrap.min.css

[image]

Heres the html code i use

```
<div class="modal-body">
                <h3>Login with your CZCNR account!</h3>
                <form name="regitration" method="POST" action="check.php" class="af-form " id="af-form-rf">

                    <div class="af-outer af-required">
                        <div class="form-group af-inner">
                            <input type="text" name="username" id="name-rf" size="30" value="" placeholder="Nickname" class="form-control placeholder pull-right" />
                            <label class="error" for="name-rf" id="name_error_rf">Nickname is required.</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="af-outer af-required">
                        <div class="form-group af-inner">
                            <input type="password" name="password" id="phone-rf" size="30" value="" placeholder="Password" class="form-control placeholder" />
                            <label class="error" for="phone-rf" id="phone_error_rf">Password is required.</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-theme-sm btn-theme" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button class="btn btn-theme-sm btn-theme btn-theme-primary">Login</button>
            </div>
            </form>
            </div>
```

Any help would be appreciated 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can give Bootstrap the number of "columns" that an entry can use, see [Grid](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp)

Comment: you can use dive the row into column and add `form-horizontal` class to your form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-2">
<div class="modal-body ">
                <h3>Login with your CZCNR account!</h3>
                <form name="regitration" method="POST" action="check.php" class="af-form " id="af-form-rf">

                    <div class="af-outer af-required">
                        <div class="form-group af-inner">
                            <input type="text" name="username" id="name-rf" size="30" value="" placeholder="Nickname" class="form-control placeholder pull-right" />
                            <label class="error" for="name-rf" id="name_error_rf">Nickname is required.</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="af-outer af-required">
                        <div class="form-group af-inner">
                            <input type="password" name="password" id="phone-rf" size="30" value="" placeholder="Password" class="form-control placeholder" />
                            <label class="error" for="phone-rf" id="phone_error_rf">Password is required.</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-theme-sm btn-theme" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button class="btn btn-theme-sm btn-theme btn-theme-primary">Login</button>
            </div>
            </form>
            </div>   </div>   </div>
```

**[Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ut5sbqvz/508/)**

Answer (score -2):

You can add a width style attribute in your very first div tag.

```html
<div class="modal-body" style="width:400px;">
                <h3>Login with your CZCNR account!</h3>
                <form name="regitration" method="POST" action="check.php" class="af-form " id="af-form-rf">

                    <div class="af-outer af-required">
                        <div class="form-group af-inner">
                            <input type="text" name="username" id="name-rf" size="30" value="" placeholder="Nickname" class="form-control placeholder pull-right" />
                            <label class="error" for="name-rf" id="name_error_rf">Nickname is required.</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="af-outer af-required">
                        <div class="form-group af-inner">
                            <input type="password" name="password" id="phone-rf" size="30" value="" placeholder="Password" class="form-control placeholder" />
                            <label class="error" for="phone-rf" id="phone_error_rf">Password is required.</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-theme-sm btn-theme" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button class="btn btn-theme-sm btn-theme btn-theme-primary">Login</button>
            </div>
            </form>
            </div>
```